# Slow Python Red Black Tree Performance

Tags: python, data-structures, red-black-tree

The following Python Red Black tree implementation takes ~2s to execute the test function, which doesn't make much sense since the tree height is 14 in the case as the test printed out. So.. I assume I did something stupid in the code. Could you please offer some tips to speed up the code?

```
import math

BLACK = 0
RED = 1

class RBTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.color = RED


def setColor(n, c):
    n.color = c
    return n


def color(n):
    if not n:
        return BLACK
    return n.color


def isRed(n):
    return color(n) == RED


def rotateLeft(h):
    x = h.right
    h.right = x.left
    x.left = h
    x.color = h.color
    h.color = RED
    return x


def rotateRight(h):
    x = h.left
    h.left = x.right
    x.right = h
    x.color = h.color
    h.color = RED
    return x


def flipColor(n):
    n.left.color = BLACK
    n.right.color = BLACK
    n.color = RED
    return n


def insert(n, v):
    if not n:
        return RBTreeNode(v)
    if v >= n.val:
        n.right = insert(n.right, v)
    else:
        n.left = insert(n.left, v)

    if isRed(n.right) and not isRed(n.left):
        n = rotateLeft(n)
    if isRed(n.left) and isRed(n.left.left):
        n = rotateRight(n)
    if isRed(n.left) and isRed(n.right):
        n = flipColor(n)
    return n


def height(n):
    if not n:
        return 0

    h1 = height(n.left)
    h2 = height(n.right)
    return 1 + max(h1, h2)


def printNode(n, indent):
    if not n:
        return
    print " " * indent,
    (v, c) = n.val
    print v, "(BLACK)" if c == 0 else "(RED)"
    printNode(n.left, indent + 4)
    printNode(n.right, indent + 4)


def test():
    c = xrange(0, 32768)
    tree = None
    for i in c:
        tree = insert(tree, i)
    print 2 * math.log(len(c)) / math.log(2), height(tree)
#    printNode(tree, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Since this is working code, wouldn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) be a better place to ask about performance enhancement?

Comment: Profile your code to find the bottleneck(s).

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a reason you made a class for your tree and then made everything else a function as opposed to a class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did quick profiling of your program with [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). It seems, that most amount of time is spent in `color` function.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-utopic-64:/vagrant$ python -m cProfile tree.py
         4227046 function calls (3801045 primitive calls) in 3.498 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.006    0.006    3.498    3.498 tree.py:1(<module>)
  1835000    1.762    0.000    1.762    0.000 tree.py:17(color)
  1835000    0.602    0.000    2.364    0.000 tree.py:22(isRed)
    32753    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 tree.py:25(rotateLeft)
    32752    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 tree.py:41(flipColor)
458769/32768    1.071    0.000    3.478    0.000 tree.py:47(insert)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:6(RBTreeNode)
    32768    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 tree.py:7(__init__)
        1    0.014    0.014    3.492    3.492 tree.py:80(test)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

If you replace `if not n:` with `if n is None:` you should get a decent speedup.

`not n` essentially tests if [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) is implemented and then calls it. If it is not implemented then [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) is called if it was defined.

Also note, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says, that comparisons to `None` should always be done with `is`.

---

`color` is only used by `isRed` function, so you might want to remove `color` function entirely or reimplement `isRed` without using `color to get additional speedup.

```
def isRed(n):
    if n is None:
        return False
    else:
        return n.color == RED
```

With this implementation I got following results

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-utopic-64:/vagrant$ python -m cProfile tree_none_no_color.py
         2392046 function calls (1966045 primitive calls) in 0.985 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.985    0.985 tree_none_no_color.py:1(<module>)
  1835000    0.286    0.000    0.286    0.000 tree_none_no_color.py:22(isRed)
    32753    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 tree_none_no_color.py:28(rotateLeft)
    32752    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 tree_none_no_color.py:44(flipColor)
458769/32768    0.646    0.000    0.969    0.000 tree_none_no_color.py:50(insert)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree_none_no_color.py:6(RBTreeNode)
    32768    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 tree_none_no_color.py:7(__init__)
        1    0.011    0.011    0.980    0.980 tree_none_no_color.py:83(test)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Thanks. That really seems to be the bottleneck. Changing not n to n is None in both insert and color speeds up the code by 3x. Inlining the code of color boosts the performance further. But since it still takes ~0.6s on my machine, I'm wondering if it could be improved further.

Comment: @kkspeed I am not sure you can improve performance further without losing on readability and simplicity of the code